# How to implement tooltip in xamarin android and ios both?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to implement the tooltip in xamarin android and ios both.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this one: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/01/showing-tooltips-in-xamarin-forms/

You can use nuget plugin in android and iOS.

For android: Xamarin.Android.Tooltips [ https://github.com/jzeferino/Xamarin.Android.Tooltips ]

for iOS: EasyTipView [https://github.com/nmilcoff/EasyTipView ]

For implementation in Xamarin.Forms: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/01/showing-tooltips-in-xamarin-forms/

Hope this may solve your issue.